# Django. Модель пользователя

Tags: python, django

Добрый день.
Подскажите как можно добавить новые поля в стандартную модель пользователя? что нужно в моделе или еще где написать?

Comment: См. [соответствующий раздел документации Джанго](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого вам необходимо переопределить стандартную модель пользователя (User) в проекте на свою, кастомную. Почитать об этом можно здесь

- [Перевод существующего проекта на кастомную модель пользователя](http://djbook.ru/examples/71/)
- [ереопределение пользователя в Django 1.5](http://djbook.ru/examples/47/)

P.S Материал во второй ссылке не самый свежий (Май 31, 2013)

Comment: Ответы-ссылки на SO очень не рекомендуются.